# Trouble with parsing HTML with unicodes through Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Beautiful Soup doesn't seem to work properly(for me) in case HTML contains unicodes whose ascii exceeds 128. What suitable decoding-encoding should be used for this ?

`raw = open('index.html').read()

BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(raw)`

Error

`...stacktrace...

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 8094: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with parsing the file. Using the link you gave in your comment to Marco, doing `soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(your_link))` works absolutely fine.

It's just when you try and print that parsed data to the console that you get a problem, because it's now been converted to Unicode, and Python will try and output that as ASCII unless you tell it otherwise. So doing `print soup` rather than just `soup` in your console will work.

Comment: how would you resolve this if you can't use the **print** statement? (see more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769745/python-convert-and-save-unicode-string-to-a-list)

Comment: You don't need to, that's the whole point. It's only a problem when you're outputting in the console.